# What is time complexity of 4 nested loops which each depend on the parent loop

Tags: python, algorithm, time-complexity

I'm preparing for a technical interview, and I have a problem with calculating the time complexity of my algorithm.
I know the time complexity for two loops nested in one another is  O(n^2)
but what if the nested loop continues the parent loop. Something like this:

```
for i in range(n):
  for j in range(i+1,n):
    for k in range(j+1,n):
      for q in range(k+1,n):
        print("Hello")
```

Is the time complexity for this code n^4, or something else? I wrote a program to count each operation, and I came up with 2^n, but I have no clue how to get to 2^n from 4 nested loops.

I would appreciate if you explain your solution.

Here is the program that I wrote to count the number of operations:

```
def count_operations(n):
    number_of_operations = 1
    for i in range(n):
        number_of_operations += 1
        for j in range(i + 1, n):
            number_of_operations += 1
            for k in range(j + 1, n):
                number_of_operations += 1
                for q in range(k + 1, n):
                    number_of_operations += 1
    print(number_of_operations)


count_operations(1)
count_operations(2)
count_operations(3)
count_operations(4)
count_operations(5)
count_operations(6)
count_operations(7)
count_operations(8)
```

output

```
n: 1 , number of operations: 2
n: 2 , number of operations: 4
n: 3 , number of operations: 8
n: 4 , number of operations: 16
n: 5 , number of operations: 31
n: 6 , number of operations: 57
n: 7 , number of operations: 99
n: 8 , number of operations: 163
```

Comment: N x (n-1) x (n-2) x (n-3)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your nested loops iterate over all [combinations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination) of four numbers in `range(n)`. The number of such combinations is given by the formula for the [binomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient) **n choose 4**, which is:

> n choose 4 = n * (n-1) * (n-2) * (n-3) / (1 * 2 * 3 * 4)

This function is clearly in O(n<sup>4</sup>), so the innermost loop iterates that many times.

In general, if you nest k loops in the same pattern, then the number of iterations of the innermost loop is **n choose k**, which is in O(n<sup>k</sup>) when k is a fixed number.

Comment: So why when I run the program to count the operations is so much closer to 2^n rather than n^4? for example for n=4 we do **16** operation but 4^4 = 256??

Comment: O(n^4) means it is a function which doesn't grow asymptotically faster than n^4. It doesn't mean that the function **is** f(n) = n^4.

Comment: @SoliTechnologyLLC: Because there is a constant divisor involved, and the constant subtractions minimize the growth early on. Asymptotic complexity is only obvious as `n` gets *large*. Big-O notation doesn't care about constant divisors, as you approach infinity, none of them matter anyway.

Comment: @SoliTechnologyLLC: Also note: You're counting your operations incorrectly. The count should only be increasing inside the innermost loop; anything occurring in outer loops is lower order (`O(n)`, `O(n²)`, etc.), which is ignored when there is a `O(n⁴)` term involved. If you do `n⁴ + n³ + n² + n` work, in big-O terms, that's just `O(n⁴)`.

Comment: It's not "incorrect" to count those, just extra work that won't change the result. Since you're incrementing the counter at every loop level, and you set it to 1 before the loop, your counter will be exactly `1 + (n choose 1) + (n choose 2) + (n choose 3) + (n choose 4)` which is still in O(n^4). Needless to say, `1 + (4 choose 1) + (4 choose 2) + (4 choose 3) + (4 choose 4)` equals 16.

Comment: @kaya3: Sure. By "incorrect" I mean they're masking the big-O pattern by adding in a bunch of additional counts that make it harder to recognize the pattern. As you approach infinity, the pattern will emerge, but when you're only looking at `n <= 8`, it's going to be pretty well masked.

Answer (score 3):

Think of it this way, there are `n x (n-1) x (n-2) x (n-3)` distinct executions of the inner loop content (which is arguably what you *should* be counting rather than every level of the nested loops as well). That works out as follows (but see comment below regarding actual count):

```
  n(n - 1)  x (n - 2)(n - 3)
= (n^2 - n) x (n^2 - 5n + 6)           # Expand each partial product.
= n^4 - 5n^3 + 6n^2 - n^3 + 5n^2 - 6n  # Expand final product.
= n^4 - 6n^3 + 11n^2 - 6n              # Combine like terms.
```

The *actual* count is actually a constant divisor of this (`4! = 24`) but that has no bearing on complexity. Since complexity analysis ignore constant coefficients and all but the largest impact, this is therefore effectively `O(n4)`.

---

A good rule of thumb (for things that are power-based) is to tabulate the results and work out differences at each level of increasing powers. When the increase becomes constant, that's the power that you should be using. The formula `f(n) = n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)` generates the following table (I add the differences of each level):

```
    |        | DiffPrev at power level
 n  | f(n)   |     1 |    2 |   3 |  4
----+--------+-------+------+-----+----
 10 |   5040 |       |      |     |
 11 |   7920 |  2880 |      |     |
 12 |  11880 |  3960 | 1080 |     |
 13 |  17160 |  5280 | 1320 | 240 |
 14 |  24024 |  6864 | 1584 | 264 | 24
 15 |  32760 |  8736 | 1872 | 288 | 24
 16 |  43680 | 10920 | 2184 | 312 | 24
 17 |  57120 | 13440 | 2520 | 336 | 24
 18 |  73440 | 16320 | 2880 | 360 | 24
 19 |  93024 | 19584 | 3264 | 384 | 24
 20 | 116280 | 23256 | 3672 | 408 | 24
```

Since it becomes constant at power level 4, that's the index that should be used.

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
 O(n^4)
```

So time complexity of nested loops is equal to the no of times the innermost statement is executed in this case: 4